# SSL - invalid CN after installing certificate (getting CN *.herokuapp.com)

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I have a heroku app hosted at `www.example.com`.

I have a certificate issued for that address (`www.example.com`). I've installed the certificate successfully according to the heroku docs.

However, I how have a problem:

- when I visit `www.example.com`, I get an invalid CN error (says that it is issued for `*.herokuapp.com`)
- when I visit `example.herokuapp.com`, I also get an invalid CN error (this time the cert CN is for `www.example.com`)

So the certificates are pretty much flipped. This is still pretty fresh (<1 hour) - could waiting solve the problem?

Also: [This part of the heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#endpoint-details) shows an endpoint in the form `example.herokussl.com`

```
$ heroku certs:info
Fetching SSL Endpoint example-2121.herokussl.com info for example... done
```

And I'm getting the standard `example.herokuapp.com` endpoint, so I did not have to change the DNS settings after installing the certificate. Could that be some clue?

Comment: Did you install your certificate? There should be a `Certificate details: ...` section when you run `heroku certs:info`.

Comment: @elithrar Of course.

Comment: As you noted, I've just answered your question... when you obviously don't need answer anymore. Plus this is not the issue you had in the first place. This is actually the issue *I* had a few minutes ago, so I document it here for future generations :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have already configured your domain DNS for non-SSL, standard `http://` access, keep in mind that you need to update it again for SSL. From your Heroku account, go to your app settings, Domain section. You will see something like:

[image]

In this example, the `example.com`'s DNS should be updated to point to `example-ssl.herokussl.com` (and not `example-standard.herokuapp.com`).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a DNS caching issue on my machine. Since this was Linux, changing browsers did not work (also for some reason restarting the dns deamon).

Anyway, it's fine now.